# Scapy: Adding new protocols same fieldname

Tags: python, scapy

I am totally new to Python/Scapy. Maybe there is a simple answer to this.

My Intention is to add a new protocol. I had already read about this topic [here](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/build_dissect.html)

But what is if i got the same field in the protocol more than once? For example:

```
class IdentifyResponse (Packet):
name = "Identify Response"
fields_desc=[ XByteField("ServiceID", None),
             XByteField("ServiceType", None),
             XShortField("Reserved", None),
             XByteField("Option", 2), #2=Device Properties
             XByteField("Suboption", None),
             XShortField("BlockInfo", None),
             XByteField("Option", None),
             XByteField("Suboption", None),
             XShortField("DCPBlockLength", None),
             XShortField("BlockInfo", None),
             XByteField("Option", None),
             XByteField("Suboption", None),
             XByteField("Option", None),
             XByteField("Suboption", None)]
```

There are four fields named "Option" and four with "Suboption". Is there a possibility to combine these fields? Or must each of these fields have its own name, e.g. Option1, Option2, Option3, Option4?